# PowerShell Look Up UserPrincipalName using DisplayNames

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I'm trying to write a script that will import a CSV file, and return the UserPrincipalName from AzureAD.

For some reason, it's just not reading the names in the files and returns an empty list.
But if I manually type in the names, it works.
The CSV file only has one column, and is formatted as:

```
User
FirstName1 LastName1
FirstName2 LastName2
FirstName3 LastName3
```

Script:

```
$UserCSV = Import-Csv -Path "C:Path\to\file.csv"

foreach($user in $UserCSV)
    {
        Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $user | Select DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, Email
     
     }
```

The thing is, if I write $UserCSV = "FirstName1 LastName1", "FirstName2 LastName2" it works without issues.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change `Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $user` to `Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $user.User`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the **$user** to **$user.User** in your for each loop

Also change the **Email** to **Mail**

The final script will be:

```
$UserCSV = Import-Csv -Path "C:Path\to\file.csv"

foreach($user in $UserCSV)
{
        Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $user.User | Select DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, Mail
     
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! that solved it!!

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you